# What would happen if too many people would call voting function of a smart contract at the same time?

Tags: go-ethereum

if I have  4,000,000 users will use my voting app and in the same moment they will make a 4 million transactions to vote/ in another meaning they will press vote button at the same moment, is that possible using blockchain or the process of voting will failed ?

Answer (score 0):

They will generate 4,000,000 transactions, the network will "chew" them for a very long time (about 10 per second), but in the end, all votes will be taken into account. It is better not to do this on Ethereum.

Comment: so it will take nearly 4 days to complete the voting ?

Comment: Yes, if there are no other transactions on the network. And if it is public Ethereum, then at whose expense transactions will be carried out - they are not free.